# How can I set a cell value based off of what another cell contains?

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm building a time sheet that also tracks the costs to certain jobs.
Employees have set Pay Groups, based off the Pay Group, we know the billing rate. However, the list is constantly changing order which means going back and manually entering each rate based off PG.

I would like to have, let's say, Cells `E5:E??` automatically find the value off of a separate worksheet in the same book, based off the PG located in Cells `B5:B??`. This would save much time and decrease the chance of entry error, as the rate sheet will not change.

There are about 10 different pay groups.

How can I set a cell value based off of what another cell contains?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! More details are needed about what you have researched and attempted to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm exactly sure what you're asking but I think you want to use the VLOOKUP function.  http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/13780/using-vlookup-in-excel/

Note to mod: I would comment but don't have enough rep yet.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Pay Group information is on a sheet called `Pay Group` and in Columns A and B (Paygroup in column A, Rate in Column B).

Now in your data table in Cell `E5` enter the following formula

```
=VLOOKUP(B5,'Pay Group'!A:B,2,FALSE)
```

Then drag the formula down.

In essence, this formula looks for the value found in B5 in Column A of the `Pay Group` sheet. Then it returns the result from column 2 of the `Pay Group` sheet (or the corresponding rate.